# Error when removing a column from DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to export a `DataGridView` to PDF, based on user `CheckBox` selection.

When I remove some columns from the 'copy' of the `DataGridView`, I get a general error:

> **An unhandled exception of type
>   'system.reflection.targetinvocationexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll**
>
> Additional information: exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

This is my code:

```
var gridViewToExport = dataGridView1; 

foreach (var columnIndex in columnsToRemove) //columnsToRemove is a List of int
{
    gridViewToExport.Columns.Remove(gridViewToExport.Columns[columnIndex]); //This is the line where the error is thrown.
}
```

More code:

```
var gridViewToExport = new DataGridView();
await Services.LoadDataAsync(gridViewToExport);

foreach (var columnIndex in columnsToRemove.OrderByDescending(x => x))
{
    gridViewToExport.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex); 
}
try
{
    string contactInfo = metroTextBoxContact.Text;
    Services.ContactInfo = contactInfo;
    Services.ExportToPdf(gridViewToExport);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

`LoadDataAsync Function`

```
    public async static Task LoadDataAsync(DataGridView gridView)
    {
        const string getDataQuerySql = @"My query string";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                await connection.OpenAsync();

            var command = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = connection, 
                CommandType = CommandType.Text, 
                CommandText = getDataQuerySql,
                CommandTimeout = 20000
            };

            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                var table = new DataTable();

                adapter.Fill(table);
                gridView.DataSource = table;
                gridView.Update();
                gridView.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The event is probably raised before the elements are fully loaded or the references are still unset, hence the exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You should work on your gridview removing columns in descending order

```
   foreach (var columnIndex in columnsToRemove.OrderByDescending(x => x)
   {
        gridViewToExport.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex); 
   }
```

If you remove the columns following an increasing order you could end up with indexes pointing to columns no more existing

Comment: It makes sense.. But still does not working.. Same error again .

Comment: Try to use RemoveAt instead of Remove

Comment: Still same error? A different message now? As is this should work unless there is a situation of multithreading at work here. Did you call this code in the same thread of your main application?

Comment: Probably the source of your problem is something inside the LoadDataAsync method. Can you add that code?

Comment: Sure.. Check now.. I've deleted the query string because it's pretty long. Note that the function works fine when I display data on my form DataGridView.

Comment: Problem is probably the Async calls. Remove them and see if the code works